# Regular Expression, testing for numbers

Tags: regex

I'm just starting to learn regular expressions, and one of the questions was to match the different types of numbers. The ones that I needed to match are in below:

my regex:   `-?\d+,?\d+\.?e?\d+`

1. 3.14529
2. -255.34
3. 128
4. 1.9e10
5. 123,340.00

however, from my regular expression, I failed to meet the first one and the fourth one. I saw the solution but I did not quite understand why it uses brackets. Can anyone explain? Thank you!

Comment: Start simple. Your regex does not match `7` or `42`. Why not?

Comment: `/-?\b(\d?,?\d?\d?\.?\d+e?\d+\b|\b\d{1,}\b)/g` [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/eNvNWj/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex does not allow digits to follow a literal dot when you only have one digit preceding it. This is because you have twice  a `\d+` before matching the dot. In general, you have three mandatory `\d+` in there, so you cannot match anything with less than three digits.

I would suggest this regex:

[`^-?\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?(e\d+)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/a9ZlIr/1)

Comment: Can you explain to me what the bracket does? Thanks!

Comment: You mean the parentheses or the braces?

Comment: the parentheses.

Comment: The parentheses are used here to indicate what the `*` or `?` following them refers to. So `(,\d{3})*` means the combination of `,\d{3}` is optional and can be repeated. If the parentheses would not be there, the `*` would only apply to `\d{3}`, not the `,`.